# Get rendered HTML output

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Is there js/npm modules of obtaining the rendered output from HTML (without parsing the HTML). Say for example I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="st_view recipe-tab ingredients st_view_first st_view_active" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;">
          <h1 class="tab-hint">
            Yields: <span itemprop="recipeYield" class="tab-hint-value">2 Servings</span>
          </h1>
<ol>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">1 <strong> Banana Nut Muffin Bar</strong>
  </li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">3 tablespoons <strong>Vanilla Milkshake Protein Powder</strong>
  </li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">1
    <sup>1</sup>⁄
    <sub>2</sub> tablespoons banana, mashed
  </li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">
    <sup>1</sup>⁄
    <sub>2</sub> tablespoon unsweetened almond milk
  </li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">1 teaspoon walnuts, crushed
  </li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">
    <sup>1</sup>⁄
    <sub>4</sub> teaspoon banana extract
  </li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">
    <sup>1</sup>⁄
    <sub>4</sub> teaspoon zero-calorie sweetener
  </li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">Pinch of cinnamon 
  </li>
</ol>                                                                                                          </div>
```

This renders the following output:

[image]

Is there anyway to access the rendered lines above (without actually parsing through the HTML ) ?

Eg: `var lineSix = getLineSixFromRenderedHTML(html);`

Edit: I want to do this in an node js server side environment (without using jquery) and I dont want to parse the html to go through individual elements to construct my output. I just want access to the rendered line (not the HTML).

Comment: Could you assign an `id` to that line and use that to select it in javasript?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to get the 6th element in your html document? Because you can do that with just some simple javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp

Comment: @SimonHyll In general please don't use w3schools as a reference, use MDN (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) or some other place that is more reputable.

Comment: @SimonHyll can you provide an example ?

Comment: @mscdex why use a more reputable site for something as simple as this? They're not wrong about these simple things. It doesn't matter what its reputation is as long as its information is correct.

Comment: Because w3schools if often wrong, severely out of date, doesn't go into enough detail, and is just a bad resource overall. Why link a less reliable source when a much better one exists?

Comment: The question asked at the beginning, regarding *obtaining the rendered output from HTML (without parsing the HTML)*, is impossible. The rendering of HTML is not possible without first parsing it. It is also not entirely clear what you mean by assigning the rendered lines to a variable in JavaScript. What would that variable contain? An image? A PDF?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have removed that assigning to variable (just caused indirection and confusion) ...however Iam sure that Thai Tran  below has answered the question. Just in the process if verifying

Comment: @SimonHyll: Because every link that links back to w3schools will cause google to rank it above MDN. Why promote a site that's often wrong vs a site that's more correct?

Comment: Because about these simple things it doesnt matter which site is used. You cant be more correct than correct. MDN is more useful if you need accurate in-depth info or a reference, w3school has nicer, to the point tutorials that are *easy to find*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/werk85/node-html-to-text) is what you need, though I am not so sure how complicated your real string is

```
var str = `your-very-long-html-string`;

var htmlToText = require('html-to-text');
var text = htmlToText.fromString(str, {
    wordwrap: 130
});
console.log(text);
```

Result

```
YIELDS: 2 SERVINGS
 1. 1 Banana Nut Muffin Bar
 2. 3 tablespoons Vanilla Milkshake Protein Powder
 3. 1 1⁄ 2 tablespoons banana, mashed
 4.  1⁄ 2 tablespoon unsweetened almond milk
 5. 1 teaspoon walnuts, crushed
 6.  1⁄ 4 teaspoon banana extract
 7.  1⁄ 4 teaspoon zero-calorie sweetener
 8. Pinch of cinnamon
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it if you give an id to every single li tag, then using jquery get the html inside the tag.

For example:

```
<li itemprop="ingredients" id="ingredient_6">1
    <sup>1</sup>⁄
    <sub>2</sub> tablespoons banana, mashed
</li>
```

And then with jQuery:

`var lineSix = $('#ingredient_6').html();`

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for this example.

It uses jQuery, mostly for simplicity, if you don't want jQuery you'll have to look at their source code and recreate the function I guess. Note that if run here you'll get a slightly wonky behavior because the runner adds the script and style in the wrong place.

```js
console.log($("html").find("*").toArray()[0]);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
hello
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the `.innerHTML` and `.outerHTML` properties. Using your example HTML, you can do this:

```
var list = document.querySelector('ol');
list.innerHTML;
list.outerHTML;
```

List returns a DOM node, which has a `children` property. To access the 6th item in the `<ol>` list, you can just use:

```
var 6thChild = list.children[5];
6thChild.innerHTML;
6thChild.outerHTML;
```